# How Do I List All the Values in a Java Attributes Object?

Tags: java, ldap

I know there is a simple answer but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Below is a small snippet of code. Can someone tell me how to list all the attributes and their associated values for the rsa object?

Thanks in advance,

```
NamingEnumeration answer = executeSearch(context,env,sBaseDN);
while (answer.hasMore()) {  // For each ou

   SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
   Attributes rsa = sr.getAttributes();
   // How do I list all the attributes that were returned?
```

Comment: Simple: `rsa.getAll()` and iterate the `NamingEnumeration` obtained.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: `for (NamingEnumeration ne = rAttrs.getAll(); ne.hasMore(); ) {
    Attribute nAttr = (Attribute) ne.next();`, rAttrs being the `Attributes` object. something like that? ([source](http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/naming/directory/SearchResult/getAttributes().html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the collection of NamingEnumerations by calling the `getAll()` method of Attributes and then iterate over this collection to get attributes values, like:

```
try {
    for (NamingEnumeration attr = rsa.getAll(); attr.hasMore();) {
        Attribute attribute= (Attribute) attr.next();
        System.out.println("Attribute id: " + attribute.getID());

        for (NamingEnumeration val = attribute.getAll(); val.hasMore();){
            System.out.println("Attribute value: " + val.next());    
        }

    }
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```